# Unifying Jenkins console logs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have a nightly build of our projects and each of them has several downstream jobs, and I configured Jenkins to send the build logs when the main job ends. The problem is that the main console only shows the details of its own job, and from the downstream jobs it shows this:

```
Waiting for the completion of "Project BBB"
"Project BBB" #41 completed. Result was SUCCESS
```

Is there any way I could make it show the details of the downstream jobs?

```
Started by upstream project "Project AAA" build number 38
originally caused by:
Started by user "User Name"
Building in workspace C:\WORKSPACE\Project BBB
Reverting C:\WORKSPACE\Project BBB\. to depth infinity with ignoreExternals: true
Updating https://111.111.111.111/svn/Project BBB at revision '2014-10-10T11:00:11.785 +0100'
At revision 43143
no change for https://111.111.111.111/svn/Project BBB since the previous build
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Or at least send the downstream jobs build.log also?

Answer (score 1):

The build log of each completed job is available in plain text:

`http://<jenkins_server>/job/<job_name>/<job_number>/consoleText`

In your downstream job, you can pull this log into a file, and simply `cat` it out in the downstream's console log.